# Envio de email para muitas pessoas

Tags: php

Quero enviar um e-mail para muitas pessoas mais não funciona quando tento mandar para umas 5 vai. Código .php

```
    <?
            require('config.php');
    $sqlstt = "SELECT * FROM tb_site WHERE id='1'";
    $resultstt = mysql_query($sqlstt);   
    $rowtt = mysql_fetch_array($resultstt);

    $sitename = $rowtt['sitename'];
    $supmails = $rowtt['sitepp']; // E-mail Suporte.
    $supmail  = ""; // Envio do email.
    $nome_remetente = "Email Marketing $sitename";   
    $assunto = strtoupper($user).", E-Mail Marketing";
    $email_remetente = $supmails;
        // Inicio do envio de menságem para o usuário //    




        // Conteudo do e-mail (voce poderá usar HTML) //

        $mensagem = "
teste msg
        ";


        // Cabeçalho do e-mail. Nao é necessário alterar geralmente...


        $cabecalho =    "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";

        $cabecalho .=   "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";

        $cabecalho .=   "From: \"{$nome_remetente}\" <{$email_remetente}>\n";

        $cabecalho .= "Bcc: email@email.com  \n";


        // Dispara e-mail e retorna status para variável


        $status_envio = @mail ($assunto, $mensagem, $cabecalho);


        // Se mensagem foi enviada pelo servidor…


        if ($status_envio)

        {  echo "Uma menságem foi enviada para o e-mail do usuário!<br />";

        }


        // Se mensagem nao foi enviada pelo servidor…


        else    {
            echo "Nao conseguimos enviar a sua menságem ao usuário!<br />";

       }


        ?>
```

Comment: Você consegue enviar para ao menos uma ou duas pessoas? Se sim então esse não deve ser um problema de código. A maioria dos [MTAs](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/MTA) possuem regras bem definidas sobre saída de e-mails. Soluções de E-mail marketing geralmente usam MTAs dedicados com restrições mais relaxadas (simplesmente para que os e-mails possam parar na caixa de SPAM do lado do destinatário :D).

Comment: Consigo enviar para 50 pessoas mais do que isso não envia tem como alterar o limite?

Comment: Você está buscando criar campanhas de mail-marketing ou similar. Quando estamos trabalhando com grandes volumes de e-mails existem vários fatores a serem considerados além do código em si (veja essa resposta do SOen: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3860043/664577). Vários fatores podem estar limitando seu envio, começando pelos próprios filtros de saída do MTA conforme meu comentário acima.

Comment: Em suma, meu conselho aqui é envolver as equipes de infraestrutura e redes (você vai precisar de uma conta privilegiada para mandar e-mails em massa, bem como toda uma preparação de infraestrutura para não sobrecarregar seus servidores). Também não recomendo que você tente escrever algo do zero (são muitos detalhes a serem pensados), ao invés disso use uma das muitas opções de ferramentas existentes (Mailman,  SwiftMailer, PHPList, OpenEMM, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Pelo visto o problema não é em seu código. Como dito nos comentários, parece ser a limitação imposta pelo servidor.

Se quiser continuar utilizando o seu código e não contratar um serviço de mailing, altere-o para que envie um número X de emails a cada hora. Este número X deve ser igual ou inferior ao limite permitido pelo servidor.

Adicione uma informação no banco de dados para aqueles destinatários aos quais  já enviou email, assim no próximo ciclo você traz somente os que ainda não tem esta informação gravada.

Pode agendar em  cron (no Linux), ou no agendador de tarefas do Windows, para que ele rode seu script a cada 61 minutos, assim você evita o bloqueio de hora.

Verifique também se seu servidor bloqueia um volume acumulado no dia.