# Enviar e-mail para várias pessoas no php

Tags: php

To fazendo um script para enviar vários e-mails ao mesmo tempo mais quando adiciono a lista de e-mails não funciona, mais quando coloco um funciona:

```
$cabecalho .= "Bcc: email@email.com  \n";
```

Comment: Essa pergunta parece um desdobramento [dessa outra](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25874/envio-de-email-para-muitas-pessoas)

Answer (score 0):

Se não me engano era só colocar separado por vírgulas:

$cabecalho .= "Bcc: email@email.com, email2@email.com  \n";

Comment: Coloco mais de mil e-mails separados com virgula mais não chega nas caixas de e-mail e nem em spam.

Comment: O problema é a quantidade? Se for 3 pessoas funciona?